# Vim: What is the status bar code for the view of command being entered?

Tags: vim

I used to (in less customized vim) get a little field in the status bar that would show me what I was typing as a command, e.g. if I enter `99dd` it would display `99d` as i typed it in.

Since updating my `statusline` to something (it used to be unset) this has now disappeared. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for

```
:set showcmd
```

Actually, it's not inside the *statusline*, but below, in the space occupied by the command-line (and ruler, if no statusline is visible).

Since this is on by default (except on Unix), you should investigate where it was turned off, and fix it there (or just set it in your `.vimrc`):

```
:verbose set showcmd?
```

Comment: "Last set from ~/.vimrc". Not helpful as my vimrc does not mention `showcmd`.

Comment: It may be under its short name `'[no]sc'`. Anyway, does it help when you `:set showcmd` in your `.vimrc`?!

Comment: Could it perhaps be something like `set nocompatible` that disables it?

Comment: Yeah. `:set showcmd` definitely works. Mysterious though because no references to `sc`, `nosc`, or `showcmd` were present

Comment: It's off by default on Unix; I've edited that in. You're fine, and thanks for accepting!

Comment: Looks like it is `nocompatible`. If i put `set showcmd` before `set nocompatible`, it doesn't work. But not if I put it after.